# having multiple sender in grails

Tags: email, grails, jakarta-mail

I need to create a app for people which can send email, from anyone to anyone 
I have tried using mail plugin in grails

```
mail {
    host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 465
    username = "adityasoni051293@gmail.com"
    password = "aditya051293"
    props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
  }
```

how ever I am not able to change the sender from application,
I have tried the following code in my controller

```
      def defaultFrom = grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.default.from
      String oldUsername = grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.mailSender.username
      String oldPassword = grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.mailSender.password

      // Change the properties here; send the email
      try {
                grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.default.from = "${parent_personal_data.email}"
                grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.mailSender.username = "${parent_personal_data.email}"
                grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.mailSender.password = "${parent_data.password}"
                sendMail {
                    to "${employee_personal_data.email}"
                    subject "new task"
                    body "you have been added to project and you are given a task"
                }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {

                  // catch block code
      }
      // Set the original settings back
      finally {
          grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.default.from = defaultFrom
          grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.mailSender.username = oldUsername
          grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.mailSender.password = oldPassword
```

but it is also using the id i set in config.groovy.
is there any way out.
or any other other plugin that I can use 
please help I am waiting..... thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is the fact the Grails Mail plugin is not designed to have it's host/port/username/password/connection properties changed at runtime. It's designed to work with one setting defined in `Config.groovy`.

If you need to be able to set that information at runtime then you will have to use [Java Mail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) directly. Fortunately, you can look at the [source code](https://github.com/gpc/grails-mail) for the Grails Mail plugin to give you some ideas and even leverage the Spring Framework (Grails is built on Spring) for sending [mail](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem. 
You can pass config to MailService#sendMail method.

```
`MailMessage sendMail(Config config, @DelegatesTo(strategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST, value = MailMessageBuilder) Closure callable)`
```

Here is an example: https://github.com/rgorzkowski/grails-multiple-mail-senders/blob/master/grails-app/services/pl/stepwise/EmailNotificationService.groovy

and source code https://github.com/rgorzkowski/grails-multiple-mail-senders